# Apache Tomcat Is Not Replace \n In JSP

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have a database text with inside " \n " characters. When I am try to replaceAll function in JSP,

```
        String SonucAc = ""+rs_aciklamalar.getString("DATA");
        String SonucAc1 = SonucAc.replaceAll("\n", " ");
```

like this, it is working in Netbeans IDE locally, but when I upload it to server inside Apache Tomcat, it is not working and \n appear again. I also try to " \n " but also it is not working too.

How can I delete them ?

Comment: Instead of \n, use system property as System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: @Rajashekhar how can I remove that ?

Comment: String SonucAc1 = SonucAc.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking the string with \n removed use the following code which is your code with little modification

```
String SonucAc = ""+rs_aciklamalar.getString("DATA");
String SonucAc1 = SonucAc.replace("\n", "");
```

I hope it solves your problem